# Conditionally rename columns in list, based on separate character vector stored in data.frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, rename, purrr

I have a list of `tibbles` called `lst`:

```
> lst
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  temp1    temp2 temp3    id
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Metric 1   150  1234   201
2 Metric 2   190  3456   201

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  temp1    temp2 temp3    id
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Metric 1   190  1231   202
2 Metric 2   120  3356   202
```

I also have a separate `tibble` called `df`, with a column containing character vectors to rename the columns in `lst`:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  colnames                                                      id
  <chr>                                                      <dbl>
1 c(' ','Ranking 1 for School A', 'Ranking 2 for School A')    201
2 c(' ', 'Ranking 1 for School B', 'Ranking 2 for School B')   202
```

I'm looking for a way, ideally using some form of `map` from `purrr`, to drop the `id` column and rename the columns for each `tibble` in `lst`, based on the values in `df`.

Any advice is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Desired output:

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  ` `      `Ranking 1 for School A` `Ranking 2 for School A`
  <chr>                       <dbl>                    <dbl>
1 Metric 1                      150                     1234
2 Metric 2                      190                     3456

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  ` `      `Ranking 1 for School B` `Ranking 2 for School B`
  <chr>                       <dbl>                    <dbl>
1 Metric 1                      190                     1231
2 Metric 2                      120                     3356
```

Data:

```
lst <- list(structure(list(temp1 = c("Metric 1", "Metric 2"), temp2 = c(150, 
190), temp3 = c(1234, 3456), id = c(201, 201)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
    temp1 = c("Metric 1", "Metric 2"), temp2 = c(190, 120), temp3 = c(1231, 
    3356), id = c(202, 202)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))

df <- structure(list(colnames = c("c(' ','Ranking 1 for School A', 'Ranking 2 for School A')", 
"c(' ', 'Ranking 1 for School B', 'Ranking 2 for School B')"), 
    id = c(201, 202)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken at facevalue, this is what I would do,

```r
library(tidyverse)

1:length(lst) %>% map(
        .f = function(x) {
                
                # Store list
                tmp <- lst[[x]] %>% 
                        select(-"id")
                
                
                # Rename Colums
                colnames(tmp) <- paste((df[x,"colnames"])) %>%
                                    parse(text = .) %>% 
                                       eval()
                
                # Return the modified data 
                tmp
                
        }
)
```

**Note:**
This, obviously, assumes that `lst` and the `colnames` are stored sequentially, such that `index 1` in `list` uses `index 1` in `df[,"colnames"]`.

Comment: This is awesome, I definitely need to develop a better understanding of `parse` and `eval`. Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome! I'll modify my answer though, I see that I forgot to remove the ID column as you desired!

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)

map2(lst, pmap(df, ~.), ~ set_names(.x[-4], eval(parse(text = .y))))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   ` `      `Ranking 1 for School A` `Ranking 2 for School A`
#>   <chr>                       <dbl>                    <dbl>
#> 1 Metric 1                      150                     1234
#> 2 Metric 2                      190                     3456
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   ` `      `Ranking 1 for School B` `Ranking 2 for School B`
#>   <chr>                       <dbl>                    <dbl>
#> 1 Metric 1                      190                     1231
#> 2 Metric 2                      120                     3356
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution, but this doesn't work with the supplied data. The reason your solution works is because the values in `nms` are actually character vectors, not character vectors stored within a `data.frame` or `tibble`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following solution. First we separate the `colname` variable in the second data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(colnames = gsub("[c()]", "", colnames)) %>%
  separate(colnames, into = paste("col", 1:3, sep = "_"), sep = ",\\s?") -> DF

DF
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  col_1 col_2                   col_3                      id
  <chr> <chr>                   <chr>                   <dbl>
1 ' '   'Ranking 1 for Shool A' 'Ranking 2 for Shool A'   201
2 ' '   'Ranking 1 for Shool B' 'Ranking 2 for Shool B'   202
```

Then we use it to change the old column names in the elements of our list:

```
lst %>%
  map(~ .x %>% 
        set_names(DF %>% filter(id == .x$id) %>% unlist()) %>%
        select(-length(.)))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  `' '`    `'Ranking 1 for Shool A'` `'Ranking 2 for Shool A'`
  <chr>                        <dbl>                     <dbl>
1 Metric 1                       150                      1234
2 Metric 2                       190                      3456

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  `' '`    `'Ranking 1 for Shool B'` `'Ranking 2 for Shool B'`
  <chr>                        <dbl>                     <dbl>
1 Metric 1                       190                      1231
2 Metric 2                       120                      3356
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you preferred tidyverse answers and already have at least one good one. So I thought I'd share a non-tidyverse approach in case anyone that comes along later is interested...

```
library(qdapRegex)
for(i in 1:length(lst)){
  # extract field names based on 'id'
  new_names <- qdapRegex::rm_between(df[df$id == lst[[i]]$id,"colnames"], "'", "'", extract = TRUE)
  # rename fields
  names(lst[[i]]) <- new_names[[1]]
  # drop NA field
  lst[[i]] <- lst[[i]][!is.na(names(lst[[i]]))]
}
```